# Making font size / margin size shrink according to screen size?

Tags: android, xml

My app looks fine on bigger devices but on smaller devices the bottom part gets cut off because the buttons don't resize according to the screen size.

How would make them resize according to the screen size so they look fine on all sizes?

I have a bunch of buttons at the bottom part and here's the code for buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/activity_main" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.uzerjamal.cricketscoremanager.MainActivity" android:background="#E9E9E9" android:orientation="vertical">
 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" />
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1.05" android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="BUTTONeeee" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:alpha="0.87" android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" />
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="BUTTONeeee" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:alpha="0.87" android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" />
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="BUTTONeeee" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:alpha="0.87" android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" />
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="BUTTONeeee" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:alpha="0.87" android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" />
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="BUTTONeeee" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:alpha="0.87" android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View android:layout_width="1dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#9E9E9E" android:alpha="0.50" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="BUTTONeeee" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:alpha="0.87" android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" />
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="BUTTONeeee" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:alpha="0.87" android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" />
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="BUTTONeeee" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:alpha="0.87" android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" />
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="BUTTONeeee" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:alpha="0.87" android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" />
        <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="BUTTONeeee" android:layout_marginTop="0dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" android:textColor="@android:color/black" android:alpha="0.87" android:backgroundTint="#FF9800" />
  </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your whole xml file ..

Comment: Hi Uzer put your whole xml code in Scrollview then no problem face like this

Comment: https://hastebin.com/oyoxajipom.xml

Comment: There's not much just a bunch of buttons right now
I'm recoding the xml so theres nothing in the top half right now

Answer (score 0):

Try [sdp library](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

**1.** Add following dependency in your app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
}
```

**2. Replace dp with sdp values**

E.g. if you have width in 10dp like

```
 android_layout:width="10dp"
```

Replace it with

```
android_layout:width="@dimen/_10sdp"
```

If you want to use it java class

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
float widthInSdp = res.getDimension(R.dimen._10sdp);

int widthInPixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension (TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, widthInSdp, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

**Note: 10sdp on different device reslutions**

```
10sdp on 330dp device = 12dp
10sdp on 420dp device = 14dp
10sdp on 480dp device = 16dp
10sdp on 540dp device = 18dp
```

Use it accordingly

Comment: I tried adding this to margin but it didn't shrink when i shrunk the screen in android studio

How would i add this to layout width? It's currently set to match parent

Comment: Dps for @dimen/_10sdp are not same on different screens.

Comment: android:layout_marginRight = "@dimen/_4sdp" is giving the same result as android:layout_marginRight = "4dp"